# SQL Server 2012 - Script table As - Create to

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

OK, in SQL Server 2005, when you use the

Script table as - Create to - File (Clipboard)

You get all the information in the script for that table.

```
' 2005 Script table as...
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ModID] [int] NULL,
[Moderator] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_User_Moderator]  DEFAULT ((0)),
[ModName] [varchar](25) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_User_ModName]  DEFAULT ('None')
CONSTRAINT [PK_AskUser] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

The above code is perfect and does what I need, however. That is NOT the case when you perform the same action in SQL Server 2012.

```
'2012 Script table as...
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ModID] [int] NULL,
[Moderator] [int] NOT NULL,
[ModName] [int] NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_AskUser] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AskUser] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_User_Moderator]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Moderator]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AskUser] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_User_ModName]  DEFAULT ('None') FOR [ModName]
```

HOW, can we script the table like we used to in 2005? I just cannot believe that Microsoft would have removed this feature from their Management system.

Any idea's on this, is welcomed. Please. I have 20 tables with over 100 columns that need to be scripted like the way 2005 does, and I do not want to edit all these lines, that will be a nightmare.

And yes, I can import the database into 2005, and do what I need that way. However, that defeats the purpose of the Management Studio, and what we are supposed to be able to do within it.

Wayne

Comment: Are you sure you copied the second set of code right (I feel like it is missing some parentheses). Otherwise, I do not see anything wrong with the second set.

Comment: The only difference is the `COLLATE` bit on `ModName`? Are you sure that the 2012 server you're using isn't already set to case-insensitive? If it is, they seem to be outputting equivalent ddl.

Comment: Additionally, have you right-clicked the database name and gone to `Tasks > Generate Scripts...`? That's a good approach for doing a lot of tables as you can do them all, or pick certain objects.

Comment: Hey, guys. If you look at the first script, you will see that it has everything there, the constraint, the defaults, everything. The 2nd one has the constraints and the defaults listed below the script. I need everything in the Create Table Script, just like the 2005 does. @ DVT, I removed what was not needed for the example. @HartCO CO. I tried your method and though it generates all the tables (Which is great), it does it like the 2nd script above shows. I need it to look like the 2005.

Comment: What is the reason you need it that way? The results are equivalent.

Comment: The site that I am currently working on, is a site that the user creates their own Database name, and click the button, and the tables are created.

Comment: Interesting, I still don't understand why the modern version is problematic, but you could roll your own with some queries against the `sys` views.

Comment: I know, it is strange that Microsoft would have removed something that was so darn useful. If all else fells, I will import into 2005 and generate all the tables as you suggested above, with one clean swoop. Instead of individual tables. (That takes a while). I also opened a question over on MSDN as well, to see if someone over there can shine some light on this issue.

Comment: I'm saying, I see no deficiency with the new approach, it doesn't make sense why it's a problem, odd use-case, I guess.

Comment: You are absolutely right @HartCO. I just ran a script with it, inside of my ASP page, and it worked perfectly. If you post this information into a new Answer, I will award you. (Just for others, I had never used that type of scripting before.)

Answer (score 0):

Go to tools -> options -> "sql server object explorer" -> "Scripting" and set the options to true under "table and view options"

[image: options]

Comment: I set near about all of them to TRUE, and still generates like the 2nd example.

Comment: What's the value for "scripting" -> "object scripting options" -> "generate schema for dependant objects"?

Comment: It was FALSE, I set it to TRUE, to test, and still the same.